# get value of a row in datatable myfaces 2.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

myfaces 1.2 I have a datatable in myfaces2.1 and displaying a check box against each row of the datatable now if I select a (or multiple) checkbox(es) against the rows I want to get the row data in managed bean and want to pass those particular values into a different screen can anyone help me in getting the particular checked row values passing to managed bean..?

```
                <h:column>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox   value="#{myResourcesDetails.chkBxVal}" binding="#{myResourcesDetails.selectedValue(actionEvent)}"/>

                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText id="tblHdr0" value="Employee Id" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: blue"/>
                    </f:facet> 
                    <h:commandLink id="emNo" value="#{resList.empNo}" onclick="fn_openResDetails(#{resList.empNo});" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: olive"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <h:outputText id="tblHdr1" value="Resource Name" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: blue"/>
                    </f:facet> 
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:outputText value="#{resList.resName}" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: olive"/>
                </h:column>



                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <h:outputText id="tblHdr3" value="Project Name" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: blue"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:outputText value="#{resList.projName}" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: olive"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <h:outputText id="tblHdr4" value="Manager Id" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; color: blue"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:outputText value="#{resList.manager}" style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: olive"/>
                </h:column>

                 </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Can ypu post your '<h:datatable>' header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `chkBxVal` field to your Object that inside `resList`

Try

and change

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox   value="#{myResourcesDetails.chkBxVal}" 
   binding="#{myResourcesDetails.selectedValue(actionEvent)}"/>
```

into

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{resList.chkBxVal}"/>
```

Than when submitting to data to the server loop over the values in your List and look at the `chkBxVal` value in each of your Objects in the list...